# Magento plugin randomly is now our homepage

Tags: plugins, magento-1.4, magento

We recently purchased a Magento plugin called uStoreLocator by Unirgy. We were running the free version, but just updated to the full version.

Now that the plugin is installed, the backend is working just fine. But...

It still shows the old version on the store locator page AND that same old version has now replaced our actual homepage!!

Does anyone have any recommendations on what to do or where to look?

We are running Magento v1.4.1

Comment: If you've just paid for it then you have paid for support as well. Unirgy are in a better position to help.

Comment: Their customer support has been nothing short of awful! Broken English, vague instructions followed by degrading comments when I didn't fully understand, and now defensive emails about how it isn't their product that is causing the problem.

Comment: Well now I feel like a jerk for being defensive too.

Comment: Haha. Defensive is fine if you present a solution afterwards. :) I know that these plugins are provided "as-is," but I just found it strange that all other plugins we have added have never had any issue. 

They have pretty much told me to figure out on my own and they can't help me...

Comment: I put the same question up in the Magento Forums. If you would like to see the most recent replies, I posted them there. Didn't want to crowd up SO... http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/294010/